# Resolving domains on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS does not work

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

Resolving domains on Ubuntu is not working 16.04.4 LTS. The home server is connected to the Huawei HG8245 router, the network on the server is parsed by NetworkManager. The NetworkNamager configuration includes dnsmasq (dns = dnsmasq). NetworkManager works.

```
root@HTPC:~# systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Пт 2018-05-04 19:39:50 MSK; 23h ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 870 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─ 870 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           ├─1780 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-enp0s25.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-fc677298-2d2f-3fca-87fd-55304cb944a9-enp0s25.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-enp0s25.conf enp0s25
           └─1791 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d

май 04 19:39:55 HTPC dnsmasq[1791]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
май 04 19:39:55 HTPC dnsmasq[1791]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
май 04 19:39:55 HTPC dnsmasq[1791]: warning: no upstream servers configured
май 04 19:39:55 HTPC NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1525451995.5358] device (enp0s25): Activation: successful, device activated.
май 04 19:39:55 HTPC NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1525451995.5400] dnsmasq[0x1ece500]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.58
май 04 19:39:55 HTPC dnsmasq[1791]: setting upstream servers from DBus
май 04 19:39:55 HTPC dnsmasq[1791]: using nameserver 192.168.100.1#53(via enp0s25)
май 04 19:40:00 HTPC NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1525452000.5064] manager: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
май 04 19:40:00 HTPC NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1525452000.5064] manager: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
май 04 19:40:00 HTPC NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1525452000.5064] manager: startup complete
root@HTPC:~#
```

The /etc/resolv.conf file contains:
nameserver 127.0.1.1

Port 53 to 127.0.1.1 is listen (tcp/udp)
Resolving domains on 127.0.1.1:53 does not work, resolving on the router works, also works 8.8.8.8

```
root@HTPC:~# dig ya.ru @127.0.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ya.ru @127.0.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@HTPC:~# dig ya.ru @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ya.ru @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41427
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ya.ru.             IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ya.ru.          257 IN  A   87.250.250.242

;; Query time: 51 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat May 05 20:18:28 MSK 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50

root@HTPC:~#
```

Using tcpdump, I found this:

192.168.100.1 - router (DHCP/DNS)
127.0.1.1 - /etc/resolv.conf (dnsmasq)

router

```
root@HTPC:~# nslookup ya.ru 192.168.100.1
Server:     192.168.100.1
Address:    192.168.100.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 87.250.250.242

root@HTPC:~#
```

tcpdump:

```
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 8895, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 51)
    192.168.100.14.38831 > 192.168.100.1.53: [bad udp cksum 0x4991 -> 0xdb5b!] 27165+ A? ya.ru. (23)
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 67)
    192.168.100.1.53 > 192.168.100.14.38831: [udp sum ok] 27165 q: A? ya.ru. 1/0/0 ya.ru. [5m51s] A 87.250.250.242 (39)
```

dnsmasq

```
root@HTPC:~# nslookup ya.ru 127.0.1.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

root@HTPC:~#
```

tcpdump:

```
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 11765, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 51)
    192.168.100.14.33915 > 192.168.100.1.53: [bad udp cksum 0x4991 -> 0x36a5!] 8712+ A? ya.ru. (23)
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12556, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 51)
    192.168.100.14.33915 > 192.168.100.1.53: [bad udp cksum 0x4991 -> 0x36a5!] 8712+ A? ya.ru. (23)
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 13374, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 51)
    192.168.100.14.33915 > 192.168.100.1.53: [bad udp cksum 0x4991 -> 0x36a5!] 8712+ A? ya.ru. (23)
```

Why did the first packet come with an answer, and three others did not answer?

Comment: I think you didn't define localhost on `Bind`.

Comment: This desktop Ubuntu on it is not installed bind

Comment: What DNS server are you *really* pointing to?  Ubuntu uses resolvconf and such so your /etc/resolv.conf always refers to localhost.  Try `nmcli device show <interfacename> | grep IP4.DNS`  where `<interfacename>` is your ... interface name (like `eth0` or `enp0s3`)